# Prove that sums of powers are equal

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, big-numbers

All numbers between $1$ and $10^{20}$ ($10^{20}$ not included) are divided into two sets: one with numbers, whose sum of digits is odd and the other with remaining numbers(those, whose sum of digits is even). Prove that sums of 10th power of numbers in both sets are equal.

I've tried to construct pairs from both sets with equal sums but nothing came out of it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are 1 and $10^{20}$ included?

Comment: @martycohen 1 is included but 10^20 is not

Comment: Hint: You want to prove that $\sum\limits_{\left(i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{19}\right)\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,9\right\}^{20}} \left(-1\right)^{i_0+i_1+\cdots+i_{19}} \left(10^0 i_0 + 10^1 i_1 + \cdots + 10^{19} i_{19}\right)^{10} = 0$.

Comment: Possibly a proof by induction on the number of digits. Not sure how the 10 relates to the 20.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - your Hint is basically stating the problem in a formula instead of in words.  if it is supposed to suggest some generating function, I'm not seeing it... 
 Can you give another hint?  :)

Comment: Well, it turns a combinatorics/number theory problem into an algebra problem, which is usually half of its solution :) Anyway, second hint: The expression $\left(10^0 i_0 + 10^1 i_1 + \cdots + 10^{19} i_{19}\right)^{10}$ is a degree-$10$ polynomial in $i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{19}$. Replace it by any arbitrary degree-$10$ polynomial in $i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{19}$, or even by any arbitrary polynomial in in $i_0,i_1,\ldots,i_{19}$ of degree $< 20$, and the equality will still hold true. Moreover, by linearity, it suffices to prove it for monomials.